# css width don't work for table data

Tags: css

I have following table in my site but for some reason the style `width:100px` does not work for td. Probably some other css is preceding. I have also tried !important but it still doesn't work.

What can I do to get the width to precede all else?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>Resurs</th>
     <th>Service</th>
     <th>Datum</th>
     <th>Tid från</th>
     <th>Tid till</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">Resource</td>
      <td style="width:100px;word-break:break-all">kjslkjfsdjfj sfjlsjfklsljf slfj lsjfs flsj fkljskf lksj fsjf sdlfj lsjföslajfölsjföl afö aölfjas fasöfj    </td>
      <td>2015-02-22</td>
      <td>10.00</td>
      <td>11.00</td>
      <td>sdfdsf</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the width to work?

Comment: Why do you think that it is not working? It is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes I know its working in a Clean Project but in mine there are a lot more css and some of it is screwing this up

Comment: Then give your complete code. How can anyone solve it without having the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle

```
<table>


<tbody>
      <tr>
          <th>Resurs</th>
          <th>Service</th>
          <th>Datum</th>
          <th>Tid från</th>
          <th>Tid till</th>
          <th></th>
     </tr>
  <tr>    
        <td style="text-align:left">Resource</td>
        <td style="width:330px;word-break:break-all">kjslkjfsdjfj sfjlsjfklsljf slfj lsjfs flsj fkljskf lksj fsjf sdlfj lsjföslajfölsjföl afö aölfjas fasöfj    </td>
        <td>2015-02-22</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
        <td>11.00</td>
    <td>sdfdsf</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjka7b5j/

its working properly ,

Comment: cant say without knowing ur complete code, Some times the parent div will be in fixed width check that